# Google maps (V3) - Map container selector (using jquery)

Tags: javascript, jquery, google-maps, google-maps-api-3

I'm trying to solve a tricky problem in Google Maps (api V3)

Works nicely:

```
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_container"), myOptions);
```

Doesn't Work if I try to use a jQuery selector

```
var map = new google.maps.Map($('#map_container'), myOptions);
```

[I made this EXAMPLE](http://jsfiddle.net/7teZS/)

---

Thank you in advance

Cheers

Pedro

Answer (score 38, accepted):

It expects a DOM element, but `$('#map_container')` returns a jQuery object. If you want to use a jQuery selector, do:

```
var map = new google.maps.Map($('#map_container')[0], myOptions);
```

Or you can also use `.get(0)` instead of `[0]`, this returns the actual DOM object.

Comment: AWESOME ! What a beautiful solution