# jQuery ID Selector Not Working in Google Maps

Tags: jquery, google-maps-api-3

Trying to generate Google Map from pure jQuery way I cant' render map when I use the ID selector as:

```
var map = new google.maps.Map($("#map_canvas"), mapOptions);
```

the maps is working when I use the finding element id in simple JavaScript method as:

```
var map = new google.maps.Map(document.getElementById("map_canvas"), mapOptions);
```

can you please help me to understand why this is happening?

Answer (score 3):

Quick search revealed this:

It expects a DOM element, but `$('#map_cavas')` returns a jQuery object. If you want to use a jQuery selector, do:

```
var map = new google.maps.Map($("#map_canvas")[0], mapOptions);
```

Source: [Google maps (V3) - Map container selector (using jquery)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3839074/google-maps-v3-map-container-selector-using-jquery)

Comment: Hi tymeJV I updated the code as you posted but still not working! I also used the .get(0) method but nothing!